# BeautifulSoup find by attribute value regardless of attribute

Tags: beautifulsoup

Say I have something like this:

```
<div class="cake">1</div>
<h2 id="cake">1</div>
<sometag someattribute="cake">1</div>
```

I want to search for the keyword 'cake' and get all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Find all by using lambda and search for a given attribute value or if a class contains the value that you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """<div class="cake">1</div>
<h2 id="cake">1</div>
<sometag someattribute="cake">1</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

print (soup.find_all(lambda tag: [a for a in tag.attrs.values() if a == "cake" or "cake" in tag.get("class")]))
```

Outputs:

```
[<div class="cake">1</div>, <h2 id="cake">1</h2>, <sometag someattribute="cake">1</sometag>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and BeautifulSoup together. This is my terrible script:

```
r = '''<div class="cake">1</div>
<h2 id="cake">1</div>
<sometag someattribute="cake">1</div>'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

for i in range(len(re.findall(r'(\w+)="cake"',str(soup)))-1):
    print(soup.find_all(re.compile(r'(\w+)'), {(re.findall(pattern,str(soup)))[i]:'cake'}))
```

The output:

```
[<div class="cake">1</div>]
[<h2 id="cake">1 </div>
<sometag someattribute="cake">1</sometag></h2>]
```